# How can I fix 'Failed to connect to server SMTP code: 111' when trying to send a letter using PHPmailer and Post method?

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I'm using PHPmailer. I want to send letter to mail which I get by method Post. Yet I received such error Failed to connect to server SMTP code:

> 111 Additional SMTP info: Connection refused

```
<?php
// Підключення файлу з класами PHPMailer

require 'PHPMailer.php';
require 'SMTP.php';
require 'Exception.php';

// Перевірка, чи була надіслана форма
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // Отримання введеної поштової адреси
    $recipientEmail = $_POST['email'];

    // Ініціалізація об'єкту PHPMailer
    $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
    
    // Налаштування параметрів сервера SMTP
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'mail.example.com';  // Замініть на адресу вашого SMTP-сервера
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'user@example.com';  // Замініть на ваше ім'я користувача SMTP
    // password updated to '' for reasons, password is set on production code
    $mail->Password = '';  // Замініть на ваш пароль SMTP
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port = 587;  // Замініть на порт вашого SMTP-сервера

    // Встановлення відправника та отримувача листа
    $mail->setFrom('user@example.com', 'Yarko');  // Замініть на вашу пошту та ім'я
    $mail->addAddress($recipientEmail);  // Введена поштова адреса

    // Встановлення теми листа та його тексту
    $mail->Subject = 'Тема листа';
    $mail->Body = 'Привіт';

    // Відправка листа
    if ($mail->send()) {
        echo 'Лист успішно надіслано';
    } else {
        echo 'Помилка під час надсилання листа: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
}
?>
```

I just want to send message

Comment: Is this always happening or occasionally

Comment: Are those your actual credentials anyone can now use?

Comment: One likely reason is if you don't have the port 587 open for outbound connections on the machine where PHP is running. If you google "111 Additional SMTP info: Connection refused" you get a lot of information about this already - have you done any research??

Comment: [PHPMailer help on this subject](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/295) When I try a telnet to that address, I also get a similiar refusal. Check that that is the correct port

Comment: It's likely your hosting provider is blocking outbound SMTP, as that's very common. Have a look at [the docs on this subject](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#smtp-error-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host).

Comment: I just need some free solution because it`s for my school task, is ther free hosting on whitch it will work or how to do this on local?

Comment: How to do what?? Have you read any of our comments, and tried to act on them? We can't see your machine, or your firewall. We cannot check your connection for you, and we cannot tell you precisely what the problem is, based on the information provided. You have been shown some possible issues, and a way to troubleshoot it in more detail. Your next task is to check the firewall, and carry out that detailed troubleshooting work.

Comment: I have this on freehostingeu, I tried to do telnet to 587 port and it was success, so I can`t understand why it still refused

Comment: That's why you need to follow the troubleshooting guide that synchro posted, then. Synchro [is the maintainer of the PHPMailer library](https://github.com/Synchro), so you should pay close attention when they suggest something.